# MVC - PHP : Error clase no encontrada (archivo no encontrado)

Tags: php, mvc

Estoy utilizando MVC en un trabajo con PHP, al instanciar un objeto en mi vista para que se ejecute el método del controlador y de ahí se pase al modelo me marca error en el objeto, me dice que no encontró la clase ni el método. (según yo no se deben incluir o requerir esos archivos, ya que tengo otros métodos con los que si me funciona), esto me paso al hacer una nueva carpeta en las vistas, ¿serán las variables *get*?

```
$objeto = new clase();
$objeto -> método();
```

Comment: use App\Model\clase; te falta instanciarla